# How to get the value of a ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

This is my first time posting question here and sorry for my bad english (if found any).

I'm working on a single page application project using AngularJs and I have a trouble working on a generated ng-repeat variable.

Here's my html

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="icon icon-comment" ng-click="showComment()"></div>

    <!--====The Button(icon) Above Will Open Up This Div====-->
    <div ng-controller="secondCtrl" ng-show="commentSection" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
        <span>{{ comment.HowManyVote }}</span>
        <span class="icon icon-thumb" ng-click="commentVote()"><span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my angular's

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope)
{
    $scope.showComment = function() 
    {
        $scope.commentSection = !($scope.commentSection);

        // run a service and get the json "comments" from API succesfully      
    };    
});

.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope)
{
    $scope.commentVote = function()
    {
        // How do I vote that particular comment from here??
    };

});
```

I can display all the comments correctly but I can't access or manipulate the value of each comment via $scope.comment.HowManyVote in the second controller.

Kindly suggest a solution for me and if possible, don't mess with the html.

Comment: is $scope.comments array in mainCtrl?

Comment: where is comments array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass that variable to your function.

So: `ng-click="commentVote(comment)"`

and:

```
 $scope.commentVote = function(comment)
```

Comment: wow, can't believe the solution is so simple...and a big thanks to you.